# How to group select new GetTable<>?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql, selector, datacontext

```
DataContext db = new DataContext(conString);
var dvd = db.GetTable<DvdList>();
var query = from b in dvd
            group b by b.CategoryId into g
            select new { CategoryId = g.Key, GetTable<DvdList>()= g };
```

The error occurs at `GetTable<DvdList>()= g`

Comment: What are you trying to do ?  With `GetTable<DvdList()> = g` you're trying to call a method and assign a value to that call, it doesn't make sense?

Comment: What on _earth_ are you trying to do?

Comment: want to group product! Similar to this, but no DVDDataContext DvdDataContext db = new DvdDataContext();
         var q = from b in db.DvdLists
         group b by b.CategoryId into g
      select new { CategoryID = g.Key, DvdLists = g };

Comment: You still don't make any sense.  You don't need a `select` clause at all.

Comment: Another thing which doesn't make sense is tagging Linq-to-Sql question with Entity Framework tag.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax makes no sense whatsoever.

If you just want the contents of the group, you don't need a `select` clause at all; the `group` clause returns a set of `IGrouping<String, DvdList>` that is itself a set of DVDs.

Answer (score 1):

`GetTable<DvdList>()= g` is syntactically invalid. The left side declares the name of the property in the anonymous type that is created. `<`, `>`, `(` and `)` are invalid characters inside the name of a property.